# Class method attribute inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method, python-decorators

I would like to build a class which has a class method returning an instance of the class instantiated with any of a pre-determined set of default values, pulled from a private class attribute. I'm finding, however, that if I create a *child* class with the private class attribute overriden, the class method still seems to use the parent class's version! Why is this happening?

Here's a MWE demonstrating the issue:

```
class MyCoolBeansClass:

    __MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr = {'FizzBuzz': {'foo': 'Fizz', 'bar': 'Buzz'},
                                 'WimWam': {'foo': 'Wim', 'bar': 'Wam'}}

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    def __str__(self):
        return 'foo: {foo}\tbar: {bar}'.format(foo=self.foo, bar=self.bar)

    @classmethod
    def specificBeanz(cls, cbtype, printclass=False):
        """ Create a specific instance from a pre-determined set of instances """
        if printclass:
            print("Class Name: " + cls.__name__)

        if cbtype not in cls.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr.keys():
            raise ValueError('Invalid pre-determined Beanz, valid values are: ' + 
                             ', '.join(cls.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr.keys()))

        kwargs = cls.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr[cbtype]
        return cls(**kwargs)

class MyCubeGleamer(MyCoolBeansClass):
    __MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr = {'GleamCube': {'foo': 'Gleam', 'bar': 'Cube'},
                                'FogSnarl': {'foo': 'Fog', 'bar': 'Snarl'}}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FizzBuzz = MyCoolBeansClass.specificBeanz('FizzBuzz', printclass=True)
    print(FizzBuzz)

    WimWam = MyCoolBeansClass.specificBeanz('WimWam', printclass=True)
    print(WimWam)

    GleamCube = MyCubeGleamer.specificBeanz('GleamCube', printclass=True)
    print(GleamCube)
```

Running this gives:

```
> testinheritance.py
Class Name: MyCoolBeansClass
foo: Fizz       bar: Buzz
Class Name: MyCoolBeansClass
foo: Wim        bar: Wam
Class Name: MyCubeGleamer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinheritance.py", line 37, in <module>
    GleamCube = MyCubeGleamer.specificBeanz('GleamCube', printclass=True)
  File "testinheritance.py", line 21, in specificBeanz
    ', '.join(cls.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr.keys()))
ValueError: Invalid pre-determined Beanz, valid values are: FizzBuzz, WimWam
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, in the `MyCubeGleamer.specificBeanz()` call, `cls.__name__` seems to be working correctly, but `cls.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr` is retrieving `MyCoolBeansClass.__MyCoolBeansPrivateAttr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. Double initial underscores mangle the attribute name in order to *prevent* children from being able to access them easily. They are *not*, however, actually private since there is no such thing as "private" in Python. Switch the attribute name to using a single initial underscore.

Comment: That seems to be the opposite of what is happening. The child class is accessing the *parent* class's private attribute in its class method, even when it has been explicitly overriden. Mind you, this works, but it's not clear why.

Comment: @Paul: `specificBeanz()` is defined on `MyCoolBeansClass`, hence that name is used when mangling the attribute name regardless of what `cls` may be.

Comment: Hm. That seems like a baffling approach to handling these sorts of things, particularly when I'm *explicitly* calling `cls.__theattr`.

Comment: *shrug* That's just how double initial underscores are handled. Which is why I never use them.

Comment: @Paul - [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references): _"Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped."_ - Its done by the parser in the class definition and isn't related to the actual `cls` used at runtime.